Thriller/horror: House that causes crimes to be committed
It is a thriller/horror where a man and his wife moves to a new home, he works for a movie archive and one day he see a police footage of a crime scene (very old, early 1900~10) that took place at his home. 
After he starts to investigate he discovered that his wife is having an affair, and she disappears. Some time later her body is found and he is the main suspect of killing her, and more and more he thinks that there is a connection between the crimes that happened at his home, the movie and his recently memory lost. 
Isn't American, if I'm not wrong is British, not old, maybe from 2013/14...

You're looking for The Canal from 2014.

Film archivist David (Rupert Evans) has been having a rough time lately, as he suspects that his wife Alice (Hannah Hoekstra) has been cheating on him with Alex (Carl Shaaban), one of her work clients. This stress is compounded when David's work partner Claire (Antonia Campbell-Hughes) gives him a reel of to-be-archived footage that shows that his house was the setting for a brutal murder in 1902. [...] When Alice goes missing shortly afterwards, David contacts the police- only to become the prime suspect in her disappearance.

Here's the trailer:



